# Como posso utilizar uma variável do handlebars dentro de um script

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Então, estou criando um projeto em nodeJS. Estou utilizando o handlebars como meu template engine e o sequelize como ORM.
No meu arquivo de rotas, crio uma rota e envio o objeto "estado" para a minha a página de formulário.

(no caso, o objeto "estado" me retorna todos os dados da tabela "Estado", estou utilizando o mysql)

```
app.get('/dashboard/formulario', (req, res) => {
    Estado.findAll().then(function (estado) {
        res.render('admin/formulario', { layout: 'admin', title: 'Formulário Administração', estado })
    })
})
```

na minha pagina de formulário consigo ler normalmente a variável utilizando a expressão {{estado}}

porém, eu queria utilizar essa variável em um script, algo assim:

```
<script>
    console.log({{estado}})
</script>
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isto? Pois, na página de formulário, ocorre esse erro:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

aparentemente não consigo fazer fazer o "{{ }}" funcionar dentro do script

Comment: Mas qual é o problema? Está acontecendo algum erro? Já tentou utilizar `console.log("{{estado}}")` com aspas?

Comment: Então, na página de formulário, gera esse erro:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

aparentemente o "{{ }}" não está funcionando dentro do script

Comment: Esse erro que você mencionou não parece estar relacionado com o `console.log`, parece que em alguma outra parte do seu script você esqueceu de fechar  parenteses. Remova o `console.log` completamente e verifique se o erro ainda acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei, posso estar falando bobeira, mas, acho que na página `admin/formulario` no Html **{{ estado }}** é uma propriedade do handlebars. Para pegar o mesmo valor de estado e utiliza-lo no **Javascript** basta fazer a mesma requisição que fez no outro arquivo com a url da página de formulário:

```
app.get('/admin/formulario', (req, res) => {
  Estado.findAll().then(function (estado) {
    let _estado = estado                              // pega os estados aqui 
  })
})
```

Só não entendi pq precisa do objeto **estado** se já está exibindo os estados no Html

Answer (score 0):

Tente converter o objeto em uma string antes:

```
<script>
  console.log({{ JSON.stringify(estado) }});
</script>
```